# Help with android to chrome communication

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I have been working on creating an application that sends a string from an android phone to a server and from there sending it to a Chrome extension. I am sitting with a few options to continue, I can convert everything to websockets, I can use normal sockets for android to computer and websockets for extension to server, or I can do some HTTPRequest stuff.

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to pull off this communication. I have a php server an android application and a chrome extension that need to be connected. If there is a way to connect the android application to the chrome extension without the server I would be happy to hear that too.

I need something secure and something that can be organized based on the correct person asking or sending information. So when someone sends a string from the android application the server stores it (probably using their gmail) and when the extension asks for it the server sends it along.

Also could the server just push the string to the extension without the extension calling it? This would occur after the initial websocket connection. I guess it would just store the IP address or something like that.

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated I am just trying to make the most efficient and secure system I can come up with. I have done a significant amount of research about every aspect so I'm more suffering from information overload then anything.

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Windows Communication Foundation Services (WCF). That's what I have been using for my android applications working with a database - the .NET framework is great, and the services seem to be fairly dynamic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324

Comment: isn't .NET meant for communication on windows? I need something that goes straight to a Chrome extension without them having to install anything on their computer. I would like the simplest process for my users to make this happen.

Comment: They wouldn't need to install anything on their computer. The windows service would go on a server - your application would communicate with the service, which would in turn do the heavy lifting by talking to Chrome.

Comment: would this limit users to only Windows computer?

Comment: I saw you have a PHP server...for this you would need a windows server. Are you asking how you would get PHP to communicate with chrome?

Comment: No.....they wouldn't know anything about the service. There is only one - the one you install on YOUR server.

Comment: Well it does not have to be PHP a windows server might be okay I just am using a free hosting service that allows me to use PHP. If there is no easy online way of hosting a Windows Server online then I would prefer to probably stick with PHP where I do not have to build a dedicated server and pay for hosting.

Comment: @eric let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1329/discussion-between-doctor-oreo-and-eric)